# Port forwarding without router

Tags: ssh, vpn, port-forwarding

Feel free to let me know if this is the wrong place to ask, but I've been wondering about it for a while. I live in university housing and we have internet included. If we want wifi, we need a router, which I do have. But we can also wire in directly to the wall via ethernet, which I also have with my desktop computer. *Just to clarify, this machine is wired via ethernet into the wall, and not connected at all to my wifi network.* I'm looking to be able to ssh into this desktop machine outside of my home network, but I didn't think there was a way to port forward without a router. Is it possible to access this machine without it being on my own network?

Thanks!

Comment: Please read [Alternatives to Port Forwarding & NAT](https://portforward.com/help/alt-to-pf.htm): "There are four major problems that you may run into that would require alternatives to port forwarding. " ...

Comment: In the configuration, you describe even if you had a router, and configured port forward with respect to your intranet, you wouldn't be able to ssh into your desktop from your home.  This is due to you being behind a double NAT more than likely, if that is not the case, while connected directly to the wall port forwarding isn't necessary.

Comment: @Ramhound what would a double NAT entail?

Comment: @pianoman102 - You need to understand what Network address translation is exactly before explanation I could provide would make sense.  *I would just verify if you can ssh into your computer from home, without port forward, while directly connected to the wall.*  While connected directly to the wall realistically unless you are the Administrator on the network you cannot forward a port to your machine.

Comment: So if port forwarding is required on the network in question, you would have to port forward traffic to your router, and from your router forward traffic to your machine.  You run into the same problem, being unable to do that, due to not having the correct permissions.  *Which is the reason you should verify if port forwarding is even required.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you plug directly into the wall, you will not be able to port forward because that doesn't apply.  The place at which you could port forward is controlled by the IT department, and they're not going to do that for you, even if it's an option.  It may not be an option.

You can set up port forwarding on your WiFi router, but you will need to know the WAN side IP of the router, which winds up being the university LAN IP.  You would have to connect to that IP, and it may not be accessible outside of the university network.  Given the pressure to reclaim IPv4 network space, the odds are against you that you have a public IP.

My guess is that since you don't have the basics of networking knowledge, you're going to quickly get in over your head, or get sucked into an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

To get things going quickly, you can look cloud based services that allow you to remotely connect to your PC.  There are a plethora of Windows softwares like this, but since you're talking about SSH, my guess is that you've got a Linux box you want to connect to.  I have no idea if there are comparable Linux softwares for remote access.

If you want to learn about networking, by all means, learn it.  It's a useful skill to have.